# Android AVD Manager: Can't create new device definition (java.lang.NullPointerException)

Tags: java, android, android-emulator

I'm running the newest version of Android SDK on Mac OS X 10.9.3. I haven't had the Android SDK or any other Java development environment installed on this machine before, so this could be considered a fresh install.

Nothing happens when attempting to create a new device definition using the AVD Manager, except for the following terminal output:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.android.sdkuilib.internal.widgets.DeviceCreationDialog.okPressed(DeviceCreationDialog.java:916)
    at org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.Dialog.buttonPressed(Dialog.java:472)
    at org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.Dialog$2.widgetSelected(Dialog.java:624)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.notifyListeners(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.runEventLoop(Window.java:825)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.open(Window.java:801)
    at com.android.sdkuilib.internal.repository.ui.DeviceManagerPage.onNewDevice(DeviceManagerPage.java:658)
    at com.android.sdkuilib.internal.repository.ui.DeviceManagerPage.access$100(DeviceManagerPage.java:97)
    at com.android.sdkuilib.internal.repository.ui.DeviceManagerPage$3.widgetSelected(DeviceManagerPage.java:215)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.notifyListeners(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Unknown Source)
    at com.android.sdkuilib.internal.repository.ui.AvdManagerWindowImpl1.open(AvdManagerWindowImpl1.java:146)
    at com.android.sdkuilib.repository.AvdManagerWindow.open(AvdManagerWindow.java:94)
    at com.android.sdkmanager.Main.showAvdManagerWindow(Main.java:437)
    at com.android.sdkmanager.Main.doAction(Main.java:379)
    at com.android.sdkmanager.Main.run(Main.java:150)
    at com.android.sdkmanager.Main.main(Main.java:116)
```

Here is a screenshot of the window:

[image: The mentioned AVD Manager window]

I have tried running the AVD Manager by using both `android avd` and `android sdk` with the same results. I am able to create a new AVD based on a generic device definition and that's it.

Is there something wrong on my side or did I run into some sort of a bug?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This appears to be a bug in the framework as I ran into it using Eclipse Juno & ADT 23.0.2.  Bug report is below.

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=73280

Comment: This is it! I actually spotted this bug report yesterday, when it was ca. 6 hours old. — Now I'm simply waiting for an update.

Answer (score 18):

I had the same problem on Ubuntu 14.04. Didn't find any clean solution so far, but as a workaround **try to clone** an existing device and then edit its properties as you wish.

Comment: Yes cloning works. But you CAN CLONE only generic devices. If you try to close your custom devices, the Clone button will be disabled.

Comment: how can we clone in windows?

Answer (score 3):

This is a bug. A possible workaround is to clone an existing device definition (e.g. Nexus 7) and set it to your required parameters.

Comment: any links to support?

Answer (score 2):

Try this (Considering that the cause is a corrupted config for an existing AVD):

Go to ~/.android/avd

Check the list of AVDs. If you think one of those AVDs is causing the problems, sudo rm -r (UNIQUE PART OF AVD NAME)*

This removes that AVD. Then re-try android avd