# Accept Button Is highlighted but when I submit the button not creating the new Device Definitions in Android Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

I want to create a new device definiton in android eclipse.I have entered all the specification of the device and sumbited create button,but it is not creating the device and if I press cancel button then button is working.

Answer (score -1):

Try to select the lower level of system images by selecting lower level of Target API

Comment: I have selected the lower level api and system images but unable to create the new device definition.

Comment: .Thank you for your response. The same issue has been raised in stackverflow.Here is the link and someone has provided with the solution.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24623027/android-avd-manager-cant-create-new-device-definition-java-lang-nullpointerex